Composite Key MySQL Dual Direction Comparison
The question in the tile might not be clear for what I'm asking for so I'll add some examples below.
What I'm asking is for is when you insert a row in a table with composite keys, a single row is valid but if I swap the keys over this is also valid. This is not what I want. I would like prevent at the table level, when we try to insert a row with the same IDs but in different order to throw an error and not allow the insert.
VALID:
user_id | friend_id
1        2

ALSO VALID but I want it to be INVALID:
user_id | friend_id
1         2
2         1

Is this possible? I'm using Laravel and have composite keys already set. I have tried looking for what I'm asking but either I'm not good at finding what I'm looking for or it can't be done in the way I want.

@Shadow thanks or closing a directing me in the right direction. That isexactly what I as looking for.
